# Problem with understtanding Matchable trait in Scala 3

Tags: scala, scala-3

When I try to do this in Scala 3.2.0:

```
  // CellTower from Google Maps API class unfortunately has no equals() 
  // implementation, but a toString(), so we use this for equality
  def isEqualTo(cellTowers: Seq[CellTower], others: Seq[CellTower]): Boolean =
    cellTowers.zip(others).fold(true)((c1, c2) => c1.toString == c2.toString)
```

I get:

```
Found:    Matchable
Required: Boolean
    cellTowers.zip(others).fold(true)((c1, c2) => c1.toString == c2.toString)
```

I read https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/matchable.html, but I still don't understand the problem (and cannot create a solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you probably wanted to fold all the booleans with `&&`, but somehow forgot the actual folding operation:

```
def isEqualTo(cellTowers: Seq[CellTower], others: Seq[CellTower]): Boolean =
    cellTowers.zip(others).foldLeft(true){ case (b, (c1, c2)) => b && (c1.toString == c2.toString) }
```

This, however, would be much more easily expressed with `forall`:

```
def isEqualTo(cellTowers: Seq[CellTower], others: Seq[CellTower]): Boolean =
    cellTowers.zip(others).forall((c1, c2) => c1.toString == c2.toString)
```

(and it would also be faster, because it can return early in case it finds a `false`).

This still doesn't help you with sequences of different length though, so you probably should compare the size first.

Comment: This is the follow up try and question to make it nicer, if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73790906/is-it-possible-in-scala-3-overriding-a-method-in-superclass-with-extension-metho