# Is it possible in Scala 3 overriding a method in superclass with extension methods?

Tags: scala, extension-methods, implicit, scala-3

I tried to override the equals method of java.lang.Object by doing this:

```
  extension(cellTower: CellTower)
    // CellTower class unfortunately has no equals() implementation, 
    // but a toString(), so we use this for equality
    def equals(other: Object): Boolean = cellTower.toString == other.toString
```

It didn't get used for equality (==).

Is this impossible with Scala 3 extension methods or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am not 100% confident as I am not familiar with the details of the `extension` keyword but given that it is essentially a rework of implicits, Scala **only** searches for implicits when it can not find a method with the given signature, so they can't be used for overrides, I don't see why this would change in the `extension` rework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible: `Object` already has the method `equals`, all reference types extend `Object`, so the compiler will always take the overridden `java.lang.Object.equals`, and never look for any extension methods.

A more complete version of your example would look a little bit like this:

```
case class Foo(a: Int, b: String):
  override def toString = b

extension (foo: Foo)
  def equals(other: AnyRef): Boolean = foo.toString == other.toString

val u = Foo(42, "x")
val v = Foo(58, "x")

println(u.toString == v.toString) // true
println(u == v) // false
```

What you could do however, is to use your own implementation of `Eq` with `===`:

```
import cats.kernel.Eq
import cats.syntax.eq._

case class Foo(a: Int, b: String):
  override def toString = b

object Foo:
  given Eq[Foo] with
    def eqv(x: Foo, y: Foo): Boolean = x.b == y.b

val u = Foo(42, "x")
val v = Foo(58, "x")

println(u.toString == v.toString) // true
println(u == v)                   // false
println(u === v)                  // true
```

Same applies to `toString` -> `Show` and `hashCode` -> `Hash` (link to [scaladoc for `cats.kernel.Hash`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.typelevel/cats-docs_2.13/latest/cats/kernel/Hash.html)). Whenever you need more control over equality / hashing / string-representation, consider using the corresponding type classes instead.